# Error 1215, cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

```
create database blood_bank;
use blood_bank;
create table Employee(
    Emp_id integer not null,
    Emp_name char(20) not null,
    phone integer,
    address char(20),
    constraint primary key(Emp_id)
);

create table WorkInStorage(
    Emp_id integer not null,
    since date not null,
    emp_salary integer,
    constraint primary key(Emp_id),
    constraint foreign key(Emp_id) references Employee(Emp_id) on delete cascade
);

create table Reports_To(
    supervisor_id integer not null,
    subordinate_id integer not null,
    constraint primary key (supervisor_id,subordinate_id),
    constraint foreign key(subordinate_id) references Employee(Emp_id),
    constraint foreign key(supervisor_id) references Employee(Emp_id)
);

create table Nurse(
    nurse_salary integer ,
    Emp_id integer not null,
    constraint primary key(Emp_id),
    constraint foreign key(Emp_id) references Employee(Emp_id) on delete cascade
);

create table Receptionist(
    Receptionist_salaray integer,
    Emp_id integer not null,
    constraint primary key(Emp_id),
    constraint foreign key(Emp_id) references Employee(Emp_id) on delete cascade

);

create table donor(
    donor_id integer not null,
    donor_address char(20),
    birthdate date,
    donor_name char(20),
    donor_gender char(5),
    donor_phone integer,
    Emp_id integer not null,
    blood_id integer not null,
    constraint primary key(donor_id),
    constraint foreign key(Emp_id)references Nurse(Emp_id) on delete cascade ,
    constraint foreign key(Emp_id)references Receptionist(Emp_id) on delete cascade ,
    constraint foreign key(blood_id)references Blood(blood_id)on delete cascade

);
create table Checks(
    isQualified boolean not null,
    donor_id integer,
    donor_address char(20),
    birthdate date,
    donor_name char(20),
    donor_gender boolean,
    donor_phone integer,
    Emp_id integer not null,
    constraint primary key(donor_id),
    constraint foreign key(Emp_id) references Nurse(Emp_id)  
);
```

When I try to execute this query it says it cannot ad foreign key in the `donor` table.

```
create table donor(  donor_id integer not null,  donor_address char(20),  birthdate date,  donor_name char(20),  donor_gender char(5),  donor_phone integer,  Emp_id integer not null,  blood_id integer not null,  constraint primary key(donor_id),  constraint foreign key(Emp_id)references Nurse(Emp_id) on delete cascade ,  constraint foreign key(Emp_id)references Receptionist(Emp_id) on delete cascade ,  constraint foreign key(blood_id)references Blood(blood_id)on delete cascade  )
```

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking to run that script where the db did not exist, then you are getting the Error 1215 because your table `blood` does not exist.

For a test to prove that, if I execute

```
create table blood
(   blood_id int auto_increment primary key
);
```

And then attempt the creation of table `donor`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
create table donor(
    donor_id integer not null,
    donor_address char(20),
    birthdate date,
    donor_name char(20),
    donor_gender char(5),
    donor_phone integer,
    Emp_id integer not null,
    blood_id integer not null,
    primary key(donor_id,Emp_id,blood_id),
    foreign key(Emp_id)references Nurse(Emp_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key(Emp_id)references Receptionist(Emp_id) on delete cascade, 
    foreign key(blood_id)references Blood(blood_id)on delete cascade)
```